# Change UpdateTargetId of Ajax.BeginForm() dynamically based on form submission result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

I'd appreciate if someone could help.

I want to return different partial views based on user type:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ContractModel model)
 {
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       if (curUser.IsInputer) { .... return View("Contracts");}
       else if(curUser.IsAuthorizer) { ..... return View("Details");}
    }

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

View:

```
     @{
        string updateRegion = "";

        if (curUser.IsInputer)
        {
            updateRegion = "content";
        }
        else if (curUser.IsAuthorizer)
        {
            updateRegion = "mainPane";
        }
     }
<script>
  function returnViewOnFailure(result) { //not firing on submission failure
        $("#mainPane").html(result); 
    }
</script>
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = updateRegion, 
                                                      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                                                      OnFailure = "returnViewOnFailure" }))
    {.........}
```

The problem is when `ModetState.IsValid`= `false` my function `returnViewOnFailure` is not firing.
I would like `UpdateTargetId` be `"mainPane"` if form submission fails (regardless of user type), otherwise it should depend on `curUser`.

**EDIT:**

So, as advised I'm using ajax call to sumbit the form:

```
<script>
var form = $('#contract_form');
form.submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
            //How to check ModelState.IsValid and show errors?
        }

    });
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: `Ajax.BeginForm` is evaluated on the server when the view is first loaded so its always going to use the same `targetID` regardless of what the method returns. Secondly, your not throwing any error so `OnFailure` will never be hit.

Comment: Look at the html that is generated by the Ajax.BeginForm method. The targetId is placed in the attribute "data-ajax-update". Implement some java-script that changes the value of the attribute when submitting the form.

Comment: What if I check ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState for validity on page load and then  $("#mainPane").html(content), but how can i get the content?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, if I think throwing an error is not a right way, I thought OnFailure fires if ModelState.IsValid false

Comment: I assumed you didn't want to throw an error, but that's what `OnFailure` is for. Not clear exactly what your trying to do or why, but I suspect you will need pure ajax (not `Ajax.BeginForm`) which gives you a bit more flexibility. Depending on what your return from the controller, your can make decisions as to what to display

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you provide a small example? I want to display view in "#content" if modelState.isValid, if it's false then in "#mainPane".

Comment: I cant because it doesn't make sense. Why would you want to return another copy of the form and add it it the DOM? Not sure what you really trying to do here.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, not the copy of a form, if form is valid I want to return some view in another div, otherwise stay in the same div and show model state errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the validation is done serverside you can set the statuscode of the response (Controller.Response).

If the validation does not succeed set it to 500 (internal server error) so the ajax.onfailure gets called. Put the validationerror logic (replacing divs content) in there. Or maybee you can even change the updatetargetid in the onfailure (by javascript).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is exactly what i needed. Btw I think if I change updateTargetID, it will work only if I sumbit the form again. Thanks so much!